# s3fs read_block with delimiter lookahead?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, distributed-computing

I am using s3fs `read_block` to distribute a csv equally across multiple processes. Each process needs to be given a byte range to operate on and work independently of others. Every line in the csv needs to be processed without overlap.

The problem is that the beginning and ends of byte ranges are unlikely to be the beginning and ends of lines. So some lines may get chopped off.

For example-

My csv looks like this-

```
beer\npizza\nwings
```

And I want to process this in chunks of 9 bytes. For byte range 0-9 I will get "beer". And for byte range 10-16 i will get "wings". I will never get "pizza" because the split exists in the middle of a line

```
beer\npizza\nwings
__________^_______
```

What I need is some kind of lookahead. Where I want to get bytes between 0-9, and any additional bytes required to form the next line. Then my results would be `beer\npizza`, `wings`.

Is lookahead the right way of looking at this or is there another solution? If lookahead is the right way to do this, can this be done with s3fs or do I need a custom implementation to do this lookahead first to find the correct byte range?

Edit:

Custom implementation example:

```
    if self._lookahead:
        self._logger.debug('Performing lookahead')

        """Use lookahead to find next newline in csv"""
        self._logger.debug(f'{end - 1}, {self._lookahead + 1}')
        r = s3.read_block(self._s3_path, end - 1, self._lookahead + 1)
        if '\n' not in (r[0], r[1]):
            """Range ends in the middle of a line. Look ahead for the next newline"""
            read_length = read_length + r.index(b'\n')
            self._logger.debug(f'New end found {read_length}')
```

Answer (score 0):

From [s3fs documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/s3fs/latest/s3fs.pdf). You can simply pass the delimiter to the read_block() function.
Hope it helps:

```
s3.read_block(path, offset=1000, length=10, delimiter=b'\n')
```